# Do I need to Block_release dispatch_block_t which is in the dispatch_barrier_async when no ARC

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch-async

Do I need to Block_release dispatch_block_t which is in the dispatch_barrier_async when no ARC ?
I noticed "The barrier block to submit to the target dispatch queue. This block is copied and retained until it finishes executing, at which point it is released." in dispatch_barrier_async.

```
dispatch_block_t work = dispatch_block_create(0, ^{
    //...
});

if (work) {
    dispatch_barrier_async(_dispatchQueue, work);
    auto res = dispatch_block_wait(work, timeout);
    if (res) {
        // timeout, then cancel, I should release work here?
        dispatch_block_cancel(work);
    }

    Block_release(work); // do I need to release work when no ARC? the dispatch_barrier_async would release it if it's executed?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When not using ARC, yes, you have to release it. Press <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> (the letter “o”, not zero) and search for `dispatch_block_create` to jump to the headers (or <kbd>control</kbd>-click on `dispatch_block_create` in your code and choose “Jump to Definition”), and it says:

> When not building with Objective-C ARC, must be released with a `-[release]` message or the `Block_release()` function.

That having been said, you are already releasing the `work` below, so you certainly do not have to release it a second time inside that `if` statement.

---

Unfortunately, the static analyzer (<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>), which is generally excellent at these sorts of manual referencing counting issues, does not appear to identify potentially leaked `dispatch_block_t` instances. Still, I'd make sure you have a clean bill of health from the static analyzer.

Comment: Nice - I tried ```dispatch_release``` but that does not work (sans ARC) so was wondering how you treat the block. Anyhow, you say ... do not have to release it a second time ... I am not clear how it is released twice? I see only one - or does cancel also release the block?

Comment: Perhaps I misread your code snippet, but you have a `Block_release` at the end, but then you appear to have a code comment in the inner `if` asking whether you need to release there, too. If I misread what you were intending to say there, I apologize. My point is simply that, yes, you need to release it.

Comment: @skaak - “I tried `dispatch_release` but that does not work ...”. I'm surprised that `dispatch_release` would compile. As the header file says, you should use either `Block_release(work)` or `[work release]`. In the absence of one of those, the Leaks tool in Instruments will report the resulting leaks.

Comment: @Rob since you use ```dispatch_block_create``` I assume you'd need to release it. You are right, it did not compile - that is what I meant with did not work. All this based on a related question I answered a day or two ago and I've been wondering about it ever since. I did not bother with the header or with the Leaks tool but I did look in the manual. There is *nothing* there on **blockrelease**. Not that it matters with ARC, but I would assume something like that should be in the manual.

Comment: Fair enough. You could always open a feedback item with Apple to update the docs re manual reference counting and `dispatch_block_create`. But I've empirically verified that the header documentation is correct, namely that both `Block_release(work)` and `[work release]` prevent the leaks in MRC code.